# How to return AJAX exceptions from portlet

Tags: json, ajax, exception, portlet

In my controller I have a @ResourceMapping method that returns JSON data.
When an exception occurs I want to

- return my own JSON error object,
- and set the HttpStatus to 500.

Is this possible please?

@ControllerAdvice looked promising, unfortunately it does not work with portlets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As answered [here](https://web.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/73897553) by Kailash Yadav...

```
HttpServletResponse response = ortalUtil.getHttpServletResponse(resourceResponse);
response.setContentType(ContentTypes.APPLICATION_JSON);
response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
ServletResponseUtil.write(response, "JSON_STRING");
response.flushBuffer();
```